# How to make Fancybox adjust height upon browser resize

Tags: javascript, fancybox, fancybox-2

I am creating a Fancybox popup on a site that needs to be responsive on mobiles/tablets. It is a php file loaded within an iframe using Fancybox.

This is the fancybox code I'm using thus far.

```
$.fancybox.open({
        maxWidth : '600px',
        href : './popup2.php',
        type : 'iframe',
    },
    {
        padding : 0,
        closeBtn : false,
        helpers : {
            overlay : {
                css : { 'background' : 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)' },
            }
        }

});
```

This is what the popup looks like in a regular browser

[screenshot 1 http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/5642/ioru.png](http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/5642/ioru.png)

This is what the popup looks like when the browser is resized

[screenshot 2 http://imageshack.us/a/img13/2610/7p6.png](http://imageshack.us/a/img13/2610/7p6.png)

How do I make Fancybox resize to show the overflow and remove the scroll bar?

I understand this is a bit of a tired issue but I can't seem to find a solution that works for me.

Comment: try setting `fitToView` to `false`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, didn't do the trick though. Content doesn't scale according when browser is resized (with fitToView set to false)